# Does JOSSO support federated login ( login using Twitter, Facebook Account)?

Tags: federation, josso

I would like to know weather the JOSSO support federated login ( login using twitter, facebook and so on account).

Answer (score 0):

Josso support all this federated login using OAuth. Check for Josso version 2 in [josso.org](http://www.josso.org) and Twitter supported authentication protocols

Main Features (v2.4.2)

- Advanced Administration console
- Fully visual configuration, rollout and management Robust Identity and Access Management
- A standards-compliant stack that supports a wide range of features Single Sign-On
- Simple combined Web and Cloud Single Sign-On Rigorously tested and certified against multiple OS, Database and application servers
- Clustering for high availability and scalability
- System monitoring Provided via advanced JMX tools and APMs such as NewRelic
- User Provisioning Automatic synchronization for aggregating identity repositories and keeping them in sync Desktop single sign-on
- Password-free access from workstations to any on-premise or hosted service Deploy anywhere
- Public, Private and Hybrid Clouds Multi-tenant and White Labeling ready for enabling wholesale business models Social SSO
- Honors social identities from Google, Twitter, Facebook and LinkedIn Support for SAML, OpenID, OpenID Connect, OAuth, WS-Federation support for seamless    Cloud/Federated SSO experience
- Integrates with most commonly used stacks such as JavaEE, LAMP and MEAN stacks Multi-factor authentication support Windows interoperability
- plays nice with Active Directory for native single sign-on Supports LDAP-compliant and JDBC-accessible identity repositories
- Advanced multi-tenant  branding capabilities Bundled with user self-services SOA security
- Provides access control for both RESTful and SOAP web services Self-contained
- Runs as an all-in-one server with no external infrastructure dependencies Cross OS and Hardware compatibility (100% Java-based)